# Why would the damping factor of neutrino oscillations be negligible?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model, boltzmann-equation

In this [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0101524) the Boltzmann equation for the sterile
neutrinos is simpified to this form:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_s (p,t) -H p \frac{\partial}{\partial p} f_s (p,t) \approx \frac{\Gamma_\alpha (p) }{2} \sin ^2 2\theta \left[ 1+ \left( \frac{\Gamma_\alpha (p) l_m}{2} \right)^2\right]^{-1} [f_\alpha (p,t) - f_s (p,t)] \tag{1}$$

where $\left[ 1+ \left( \frac{\Gamma_\alpha (p) l_m}{2} \right)^2\right]^{-1}$ is the damping factor.

But in [Dodelson's](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9303287) take on sterile neutrino's dark matter the equation is simplified by considering the damping factor to be negligible, obtaining:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_s (p,t) -H p \frac{\partial}{\partial p} f_s (p,t) \approx \frac{\Gamma_\alpha (p) }{2} \sin ^2 2\theta [f_\alpha (p,t) - f_s (p,t)] \tag{2}$$

No explanation is given as to why, and my only guess is that in the early universe during the epoch in which sterile neutrino could have potentially been created, there wasn't enough particles to cause any damping. But this seems a bit farfetched.

**Why is the damping factor taken to be zero?**

Comment: try a more theoretica questions and answers site https://www.physicsoverflow.org/